# On Exchange Server enable require that all senders are authenticated on all groups

Tags: exchange-2007, spam

I have a large number of Distribution Groups on my Exchange 2007 server. I am starting to get spam addressed to these group addresses and would like to enable the "Require all senders are authenticated" option on all groups.

I know I can tick the option manually in each groups policy but that's unfeasible considering the number of groups, 100+.

Does anyone know a way to set this on multiple groups?
(Shift+selecting multiple groups doesn't allow properties)

Comment: you can use PS to do this (I believe in 2007 as well, I know in 2010).  I'm walking out the door at work or I'd formulate an answer with a PS script...but I'll check tomorrow and post if nobody else has or you don't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -resultsize unlimited | Set-DistributionGroup -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $true
```